# Search through text file and find pattern and add text in unix

Tags: unix

I have a text file and whant to add a some text everywhere I find a pattern.

myfile.txt:

> P016 text file and more text P011 text file and more text P020 text file and more text P022 text file and more text P031 text file and more text P078 text file and more text P021 text file and more text P055

Now I want to find all text that have the word P0 and add ('P0...'):

> ('P016') text file and more text ('P011') text file and more text ('P020') text file and more text ('P022') text file and more text ('P031') text file and more text ('P078') text file and more text ('P021') text file and more text ('P055')

Comment: UPDATE - Poorly formulated question of me but I changed It. Is the question still that bad?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ gsub(/(P[[:digit:]]+)/,"('\''&'\'')"); print;}' input.data
```

where `input.data` is the name of the file.